# Why does reference array y become a copy of array x, after x is e.g. multiplied with a scalar?

Tags: python, numpy, copy, variable-assignment

After creating an array `x` and making a reference `y`,  modifying `x` (or `y`) at a single index will cause simultaneous changes in `x` and `y`, in contrast to a copy `z`.

**Example**:

Create an array `x`, with a reference `y` and a copy `z`:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = x
z = np.copy(x)
```

Modify array at index `0`:

```
x[0] =0
x
Out: array([0, 2, 3])
y
Out: array([0, 2, 3])
z
Out: array([1, 2, 3])
```

In this case `x` and `y` share the same memory location:

```
id(x)
Out: 2519145124656
id(y)
Out: 2519145124656
id(z)
Out: 2519145126192
```

When repeating the example above, but now modifying reference `x` by performing a e.g. a vector-scalar multiplication a copy and not reference is made for `y`. This seems confusing. Is there a specific reason why a copy and not a reference is made in this case?

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = x
z = np.copy(x)
```

Modify `x` by multiplication with scalar `2`:

```
x = x * 2

x
Out: array([2, 4, 6])
y
Out: array([1, 2, 3])
z
Out: array([1, 2, 3])
```

`x` and `y` do not share the same memory location anymore, altough no explicit copy was made before:

```
id(x)
Out: 2519145069712
id(y)
Out: 2519145224592
id(z)
Out: 2519145196400
```

Comment: because `x * 2` creates a new array. Why is this confusing? That is how it is documented to work, and how you would generally expect it to work, based on how built-in data structures work. Note, if you did `x *= 2` that would work *in-place* and *would* mutate the array, thus `y` (a reference to the same array) would reflect that change.

Comment: "altough no explicit copy was made before" because `x * 2` creates a new array, no *copy* needed to have been made. `y` did *not become a copy of anything*

Comment: but fundamentally, you need to understand when you are *creating a new object* versus *mutating an existing object*

Answer (score 0):

- when you modify the array `x` by performing a vector-scalar multiplication `x = x * 2`, a `new array` is created in `memory` to store the result of the multiplication. This new array is assigned to the variable `x`, while the variable `y` still refers to the original array  and does not reflect the changes made to x.
- On the other hand, when you `modify x or y` at a single index, both variables still refer to the `same array` in memory. This is because modifying a single index does not create a `new array` , it simply modifies the existing array in place. Therefore, both x and y reflect the `changes` made.
- To summarize, whether a `copy` or a `reference` is made depends on the specific operation performed, Modifying a single index in an array modifies the original array in place while performing operations that create a new array (such as `vector-scalar multiplication`) result in a new array being created and assigned to the variable